# Losing SuperClass attributes in array - Java

Tags: java

I have a class that extends a superclass. There are some attributes that are in the superclass that I use when constructing my subclass (`Candidate`).  I have a test class for `Candidate` called `CandidateTest`.

The short story is, I create an array of candidates with various attributes, then I pass that array into a method. That method then goes through the array and picks certain candidates then creates a new `ArrayList` with those candidates.

Now, when I'm trying to print some of the values of those candidates, I'm getting a `null` return on the attributes that are defined in the superclass, but the values from the subclass are showing up fine.

For example, I can do

```
for(int i=0; i < googleCandidate.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(googleCandidate.get(i).getCommunication());
}
```

and it will print me out the value of all my `Candidate`'s communication value.  But if I do this:

```
System.out.println(googleCandidate.get(i).getFirstName());
```

it returns 15 lines of `null` for every `Candidate`.

When I originally created the `Candidate` objects, they had 5 values passed into the constructor.  However, they seem to have forgotten the values defined in the superclass and only remember the values defined in the subclass.

Comment: Could you post your `super class` and `sub class` code?

Comment: Which code do you want to see specifically?  The constructor?  The method I'm calling? I don't want to overload the page with code. Thanks for responding btw

Comment: We need code related to building object (class declaration, constructors, examples of attributes) and the method called.

Comment: Thank you guys for responding.  Your question about my code jogged my brain a bit.  While studying my superclass, I noticed that I did not instantiate my variables in the constructor that I was using.  So I wasn't losing any information in the array, there were no values assigned to firstName and lastName to begin with.  Thank you for leading me down the right path, the program is working now.

Comment: Please, make an answer with the problem and your correction to close the question. Glad you found yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I had forgotten to initiate the attributes in the superclass when I created an instance of the subclass.  I  had this code:

```
 public AddressBook(String fn, String ln){       
}
```

And everything worked when I changed it to this:

```
 public AddressBook(String fn, String ln){
    firstName = fn;
    lastName = ln;
}
```